# Is this partial fraction valid?

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

Hi I'm trying to do a partial fraction decomposition but I'm not sure if what I'm doing is legit math and whether it's a good approach to my problem. I have the following fraction which appears inside an integral:

$$
\frac{e^{c\delta}}{\prod_{i=1}^N e^\delta + e^{\theta_i}} 
$$

where $c$ and $N$ are integers and $c \leq N$. If I substitute $x=e^\delta$ figured I could rewrite this as:

$$
\frac{x^c}{\prod_{i=1}^N x + e^{\theta_i}}
$$
I figured that both the numerator and the denominator are polynomials in $x$ and therefore I could write:

$$
\frac{x^c}{\prod_{i=1}^N x + e^{\theta_i}} = \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{A_i}{x+e^{\theta_i}}
$$

multiplying both sides by $\prod_{i=1}^N x + e^{\theta_i}$ gives:

$$
x^c = \sum_{i=1}^N A_i \prod_{j\neq i}^N x+e^{\theta_j}
$$
and I figured that I can solve for $A_i$ if I say $x = -e^{\theta_i}$ which gives:

$$
(-e^{\theta_i})^c = A_i \prod_{j\neq i}^N e^{\theta_j} - e^{\theta_i} \\
A_i =  \frac{(-e^{\theta_i})^c}{\prod_{j\neq i}^N e^{\theta_j} - e^{\theta_i}}
$$
but is this derivation proper? Saying $x = -e^{\theta_i}$ implies $\delta = \theta_l + i \pi$ which suddenly introduces complex numbers (while $\delta$ is only defined on the reals). In addition, by introducing $\frac{1}{\prod_{j\neq i}^N e^{\theta_j} - e^{\theta_i}}$ do I introduce a lot of difficulties when I (later) plan to integrate over $\theta_i$? If this is so, my approach might not be suited for this problem.